# PDF acroform fields become non editable in Adobe reader after writing to it using Pdfbox APIs

Tags: pdfbox

I am reading a PDF which has editable fields and the fields can be edited by opening it through Adobe Reader. I am using PDFBox APIs to generate an output PDF with data filled for the editable fields in input PDF. The output PDF can be opened using Adobe Reader and I am able to see the field values but I am unable to edit those fields directly from Adobe reader.

There is also a JIRA ticket for this issue and it is unresolved according to this link :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1121

Can anybody please tell me if this got resolved? Also, if possible please answer the following questions related to my question:

1. Is there any protection policy or access permission that I need to explicitly set in order to edit the output PDF from Adobe reader?
2. Every time I open the PDF that was written to using pdfbox APIs, I get this message prompt:

> " The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available...."

I am using PdfBox 1.8.6 jar and Adobe reader 11.0.8. I would really appreciate if anybody could help me with this issue.

Code snippet added to aid responders in debugging :

```
String outputFileNameWithPath = "C:\myfolder\testop.pdf";
PDDocument pdf = null;
pdf = PDDocument.load( outputFileNameWithPath );

PDDocumentCatal og docCatalog = pdf.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
//The map pdfValues is a collection of the data that I need to set in the PDF
//I am unable to go into the details of my data soutce
// The key in the data map corresponds to the PDField's expanded name and data
//  corresponds to the data that I am trying to set.
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter=pdfValues.entrySet().iterator();
String name=null;
String value=null;
PDField field=null;
//Iterate over all data and see if the PDF has a matching field.
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> currentEntry=iter.next();
    name=currentEntry.getKey();
    value=currentEntry.getValue();
    if(name!=null) {
        name=CommonUtils.fromSchemaNameToPdfName(name);
        field=acroForm.getField(name);      
    }
    if( field != null && value!=null )
        {           
            field.setValue( value ); //setting  the values once field is found.
        }
}
// Set access permissions / encryption here before saving
pdf.save(outputFileNameWithPath);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The document has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available....

This indicates that the original form has been *Reader-enabled*, i.e. an integrated Usage-Rights digital signature has been applied to the document using a private key held by Adobe which tells the Adobe Reader that it shall make some extra functionality available to the user viewing that form.

If you don't want to break that signature during form fill-ins with PDFBox, you need to make sure that you

1. don't do any changes but form fill-ins and
2. save the changes as incremental update.

If you provided your form fill-in code and your source PDF, this could be analyzed in more detail.

Comment: mkl - I have added the code snippets as per your suggestion. The PDF I use is US govt's W-4 form or any other form that can be downloaded. Also, I have noticed that 'pdf.saveIncremental()' works only with digital signatures. It did not work when I replaced .save with .saveIncremental for acroform's fields.

Comment: Essentially you will need an incremental update or remove the usage rights - Adobe reader xi allows much more even without usage rights.

Comment: I'll look into that later, I'm currently only on a mobile phone.

Comment: so what you are suggesting is that instead of having one big fat .save() call at the end of my method, I need to call .saveIncremental() every time I set a field in my code, above, inside the loop? I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Not once per field, but your changes as a whole need to be added as an incremental update. Please look up the exact use of saveIncremental() first. I think it requires you first to copy the original file or something.